# Batch file, how to type a file and the file outputs a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi i want to make a batch file that types a file with variables from the batch file

Batch File :

```
set name="relity"
set status="online"
type test.txt
```

test.txt :

```
Name : %name%
Status : %status%`
```

Hi i want to make a batch file that types a file with variables from the batch file
`type test.txt`

The test.txt looks like this :

```
Name : %name%
Status : %status%`
```

I want the "%name%" and "%status% to get the values that i want in the batch file

```
set name="relity"
set status="online"
type test.txt
```

When it types i want to print this :

```
Name : relity
Status : online
```

Comment: What is the actual use case here? I can't see the sense of assigning the values in the batch file then subsequently expanding from the text file with the batch values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CALL` and `ECHO` commands to get the double variable expansion you would need to accomplish this.

```
@echo off
set "name=relity"
set "status=online"
for /f "delims=" %%G IN (test.txt) DO call echo %%G
```

Output

```
C:\BatchFiles\SO\77767276>so2.bat
Name : relity
Status : online
```

Comment: It doens't work, do you have discord or something so i can talk with you?

Comment: Works fine for me (except it's removing empty lines, which might or might not be a problem for your usecase). **How*  doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @relity, I get paid for one on one support.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file that replaces the variables in the `test.txt` file with the values you've set in the batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    
set name="relity"
set status="online"
    
set "inputFile=test.txt"
set "outputFile=output.txt"
    
REM Read the input file and replace variables
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%inputFile%) do (
set "line=!line:%%name%%=%name%!"
set "line=!line:%name%=!name!"
set "line=!line:%%status%%=%status%!"
echo !line! >> "%outputFile%"
)
```

Save this script with a `.bat` extension and run it. The output will be displayed on the console, and you can also check the `output.txt` file for the result.

Comment: This does not work. You need to double the percent symbols on %%name%% and %%status%% and use normal variable expansion for the replacement string. `set "line=!line:%%name%%=%name%!"` and `set "line=!line:%%status%%=%status%!"`

Comment: Also consider not using the `type` command. The `FOR /F` command is used to read files. `for /f "delims=" %%a in (%inputFile%) do` or `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%inputFile%") do`

Comment: because `type` is meant to just display the file literally, not to process it. A.k.a it can't do what you want by design.